# Why values become very large after torch.dist.all_reduce?

Tags: python, pytorch, mapreduce

I'm using `pytorch` to train a net and found that the loss values become very strange after `all_reduce`.  I've printed the related values as following:

```py
>>> print(f'{rank=}, before reduce, {loss=}')
rank=0 before reduce, loss=0.004893303848803043
rank=1 before reduce, loss=0.008418125100433826
rank=5 before reduce, loss=0.022900601848959923
rank=4 before reduce, loss=0.033665977805630645
rank=6 before reduce, loss=0.05732813761557371
rank=7 before reduce, loss=0.006465559359639883
rank=2 before reduce, loss=0.01541353389620781
rank=3 before reduce, loss=0.035168059170246124

>>> dist.all_reduce(loss.div_(dist.get_world_size()))
>>> print(f'{rank=}, after reduce, {loss=},  {world_size=}')
rank=0 after reduce, loss=-8.541948720476135e+27, world_size=8
rank=4 after reduce, loss=0.011374264427650382, world_size=8
rank=5 after reduce, loss=-8.541948720476135e+27, world_size=8
rank=1 after reduce, loss=-8.541948720476135e+27, world_size=8
rank=6 after reduce, loss=0.011374264427650382, world_size=8
rank=2 after reduce, loss=-8.541948720476135e+27, world_size=8
rank=7 after reduce, loss=-8.541948720476135e+27, world_size=8
rank=3 after reduce, loss=-8.541948720476135e+27, world_size=8
```

Now I have no idea about how to debug next. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am guessing here (partially because how loss is printed) but is it possible that the output of loss.div_(8) you send to the all_reduce is not a tensor?

Comment: @D.ACAR `dist.all_reduce(loss)` returns large strange values too.

Comment: I think your loss is not a tensor as well. can you check it up for me by printing type(loss). The reason for me thinking that is the __str__() of a tensor which prints tensor info rather than just its data i.e. "{loss=}" should have printed the tensor information in the first line.

Comment: I am not sure what goes in your actual code but that would have been my first guess. Of course I might be wrong.